# Segue to a view controller from appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have an app set up to receive push notifications. When a user receives a notification, I have a callback in my appDelegate. I need to be able to segue from here if the app was inactive and the user clicks on the notification from the panel on the device.

The flow of the app is a login view controller (which gets skipped if the loginBool is true) which leads to a tab controller. On the tab controller I have 3 places where I can segue to the same viewController with an id of "FeedDetailedController".

It is the FeedDetailedController I need to segue to and pass in a variable which I am receiving in my notification. This controller can be accessed from 3 different places 2 of which are tabs with table views, when you click on a row, it passes in a variable and performs a segue. I need to miic this from my app delegate i.e. pass in data from the notification, like what I am doing with the row.

Attempt so far:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println("received a notification")
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            println("in the notification if with \(userInfo)")

            if let info = userInfo["custom"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> { 
                if  let reportId = info["reportId"] as? String {
                    println("\nFrom APS-dictionary with key \"type\":  \(reportId)")
                    //pass in reportId to the viewcontroller somehow

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewFeedDetailedController") as! UIViewController

                    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
        else{
            println("in the notification else")
            //this is when the app is active, do I need to detect which view   controller I am currently on before I can seg???
        }
    }
```

The current code gives the following message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x12ed763d0> on <UINavigationController: 0x12ed11ce0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Which makes sense but I don't know how I am supposed to get the hierarchy right coming from appDelegate code

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to check for that notification in the initial view controller of your app? Like pass it the notification as a boolean? You could look somewhere like viewWillAppear: and check for it - if it is there control the segue from that view instead of trying to do it in the appDelegate itself?

That way it would appear to go directly into the new view, but really be passing through a view controller that has the hierarchy loaded into it?

Comment: Well I can't move the didReceiveRemoteNotification func into a view controller. If you're saying to set a NSUserDefault Bool in the app delegate and then check in the loginviewController if a notification was received and segue if the flag was set to true, that might get complex because I already have a loginBool to skip that screen, and if the user is logged in, I trigger the opening of the tab bar. But moving to my desired controller from a notification would require opening the tab bar, and then seguing to my feedDetailedController?

Comment: I can see the danger of complexity here since you have logic to bypass your initial view based on that bool. I'm not sure if it is a requirement to open the tab bar for what you need to do. I was essentially recommending having a global variable that the notification sets to tell you what you need to know in your view controller, then triggering a segue. It seems like from what you are saying, you'd have to check this in two controllers due to your login logic... so  I'm not sure if it is the "best" answer due to your concern over complexity (rightly so).

Comment: What about if I put my check in viewDidAppear in each of my tabs and perform the seg from there and reset the bool? To explain more, i have 5 tabs in my app. Tab 3 has a tableview, which when clicked segues to feedDetailedController described earlier. If the app is in the background and when reopened is on tab 2, I check in viewDidAppear for the notificationbool and programmatically segue to feedDetailedController. Then when the user presses back, they just return to tab two? Or will i have to 'keep tabs' of where the segue occurred and programmatically segue back to that screen?